# Standalone Application does not start in Chrome Verion 92.0.4515.107

Tags: anylogic

Does anyone know, why a standalone application does not start with a chrome browser (version 92.0.4515.107) on Windows anymore?

It was running until 23.07.21 and with no change in the simulation it is now blocked in loading phase. The simulation is still working with the embedded chromium as well as with Firefox.

As we checked with other models, it is only one model which faces this issue.

Comment: Perhaps raise directly with AnyLogic support. And specify if this is Windows, Mac or Linux

Comment: Thank for your answer. I edit my question and as well asked the AnyLogic support.

Comment: Pleasure. Feel free to post the answer here. One more question: Was there no meaningful output in the console window (the little black window that pops up when you run the model) we recently had an issue where it was simply that a font was missing from the OS, if we distributed it to the client with Chromium it worked for some reason...